# translate with cakephp 4

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-4.x

I want to translate the return of this function (timeAgoInWords) cakephp which in French which allows to return the date in text format

I create folder Locale in src

this is the function in my view

```
$this->Time->timeAgoInWords($v->created)
```

this is the code in my app.php

```
 'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
 'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'fr_FR'),
 'defaultTimezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'UTC')
```

but the date is alway in English

thank you for help

Comment: Your question is missing a question / problem description.

Comment: the problem that the date is always displayed in English 
for example i hava 1 day ago

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#localizing-dates-and-numbers

Comment: alway i have same result
like this : 23 hour, 54 minute ago